# Unexpected token in Gallery component for FineUploader

Tags: reactjs, fine-uploader

Just started integrating FineUploader into my ASP.NET/React/Redux app. I'm getting this error in the Gallery component. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think static is supported only for class methods in ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the the JS parser in your IDE - not Fine Uploader related. Make sure your parser supports static class properties, which are currently a stage 2 ES proposal.